# Why is IE showing a scrollbar with no scroller (scrollbar not needed and not in FF and Safari)?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a calendar that is a table.  For some reason, IE is adding a vertical scrollbar to the edge of the page but there is no scroller (and nothing to scroll)  FF and Safari look fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you mean the scroller for the entire viewport (broswer window) or the scroller for your table's containing element (presumably a div)? Also it would be helpfule if you could post your css and html.

Comment: Hi-I mean for the whole browser page.  The html and css are huge so I want to try and get in answered before resorting to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal in Internet Explorer, and to my knowledge can not be turned off except maybe with a `overflow:hidden` on the body or html element, with the obvious downside that the page then can't be scrolled at all.

If you need to get the exact same behaviour in all browsers, and want to add the deactivated scrollbar to FF and Safari, check my [**recent question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735936/get-a-deactivated-scrollbar-in-firefox).

Answer (score 0):

If you put overflow: auto in the body element and just remove overflow:auto or any other overflow setting in the other elements on the page, then the main browser scrollbar will allow scrolling down the page and the page will expand, moving the footer down as well.